# What happens to my scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, anaconda

I use python 2.7.8 with the Anaconda distribution and I have problems with scipy.
Let A be a sparse matrix; I want to calculate its eigenvalues but if I write:

```
import scipy
scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs(A)
```

I get the error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

What is the problem? (The version  of scipy is 0.15.1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
from scipy import sparse
import scipy.sparse.linalg as sp_linalg

B = np.random.rand(10,10)
A_dense = np.dot(B.T, B)
A_sparse = sparse.lil_matrix(A_dense)
sp_linalg.eigs(A_sparse, 3)
```

It seems that you have to explicitly import the submodules. `scipy` does not load those per default.